# ThisWorkbook.Close(False) leaves open Excel GUI

Tags: excel, vba

How do I close out the workbook entirely? If I close out the instance of Excel then it inadvertently will shut off all the workbooks due to the new behavior in Excel 2013.

Comment: Use Application.Quit after ThisWorkbook.close.

Comment: @PareshJ doesn't Application.Quit close all workbooks? How can I call Application.Quit when ThisWorkbook.Close stops all code after it?

Comment: Use ThisWorkbook.saved = True / False and after this use Application.Quit

Comment: @PareshJ Application.Quit closes ALL open Excel sheets not just ThisWorkbook. The default behavior of Excel 2013 is to make all open Excel sheets go to the same instance of Application.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're expecting. Please clarify what's happening vs what you would want to happen (and what code you're using to achieve that).

Comment: @retailcoder Literally I am using ThisWorkbook.Close(False) to simply close out my workbook. I want my workbook to close. There is no other code than that. The problem is it leaves open the Excel GUI with no workbook open. This is not the same behavior as simply closing the workbook. When I use Application.Quit it closes ALL WORKBOOKS, not just the target workbook because Excel 2013 puts all workbooks in the same instance. Anything prior to Excel 2013 I would use Application.Quit but this does not have the same behavior in 2013. I want the workbook and Excel GUI shell to close.

Comment: Instead of putting a wall of text in a comment, I suggest edit your question.

Comment: @CoolBlue I think if you do exactly what I put in my question you will clearly see the problem. I don't see why anything else has to be added to the question. Just do ThisWorkbook.Close(False) in Excel 2013 and you will see the problem.